# (Verification) Speed, Distance and Time word Problem Verification

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations

**Q: A boat covers 32km upstream and 36 km downstream in 7 hours. Also it cobers 40 km upstream and 48 km downstream in 9 hours . Find the speed of boat in still water and that of stream**

 MY SOLUTION:

Let the speed of boat be *x* km/hr and speed of stream be *y* km/hr

 speed of boat when going upstream: $(x-y)$ km/hr

 speed of boat when going downstream: $(x+y)$ km/hr

Case 1: when total time taken is 7 hrs

 when going upstream: $t_1 = \frac{32}{x-y}$

 when going downstream: $t_2 = \frac{36}{x+y}$

 And $t_1+t_2=7$ hours
$$ \implies \frac{32}{x-y}+\frac{36}{x+y}=7 $$
Let $\frac{1}{x} = m$ and $\frac{1}{y}= n$
$$ \implies 32m-32y+36m+36n=7 \implies 68m+4n=7 $$ ... eq(i)

Case 2: when total time is 9 hours

When going upstream: $t_1= \frac{40}{x-y}$

 When going downstream: $t_2=\frac{48}{x+y}$

 AND $t_1+t_2=9$ hours
$$ \implies \frac{40}{x-y}+\frac{48}{x+y}=9 $$
As $\frac{1}{x} = m$ and $\frac{1}{y}= n$
$$ \implies 88m-8n=9 $$ ...eq(ii)

 multiplying eq(i) with 2 
 $ 136m+8n=14$ ..eq(iii)

 and solving eq(iii) and eq(ii) by elimination: [eq(iii)+eq(i)]

 $224m=23$

---

This gives a decimal value and not a natural number.

 the correct answer is $x=10$ km/hr and $y=2$ km/hr and the answer took $\frac{1}{x+y}=a$ & $\frac{1}{x-y}=b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the speed of the boat in still water = x kmph
Speed of the stream = y kmph

i ) relative speed of the boat in downstream

= ($ x$ + $y$ ) kmph

Distance travelled =$ d_1 $=$ 36$

Time = $t_1 $hr

$t_1 $=$\frac { d1} { s_1}$

$t1 $= $\frac {36}{ ( x + y ) }$

ii) relative speed of the boat in upstream = $( x - y )$ kmph

Distance =$ d_2 $=$ 32$ km
Time =$ t_2 $

$t_2 $=$\frac{ 32}{ ( x - y )}$

Therefore ,

Total time = $7$ hr

$t_1$ +$ t_2 $=$ 7$hr

$\frac{36 }{( x + y )}$ +$ \frac{32}{( x - y )} = 7$ ----( 1 )

iii) second time ,

Relative speed of the boat in downstream =$ ( x + y )$ kmph

$d_3 = 48$ km

Time = $t_3$

$t_3 = \frac{48}{ ( x + y )}$

iv ) in upstream Relative speed of the boat =$ ( x - y ) $kmph

time =$ t_4$ hr

$d_4 = 40$km

$t_4 = \frac{40}{( x - y )}$

Total time =$ 9$ hr

$\frac{48}{( x + y )} + \frac{40}{( x - y )} = 9$ ---( 2 )

Let $\frac{1 }{( x + y ) }= a$ ,

$\frac{1}{( x - y )} = b$

Then rewrite ( 1 ) and ( 2 ) we get

$36 a + 32 b = 7$ -----( 3 )

$48a + 40b = 9$ ------( 4 )

Multiply ( 4 ) with 4 and equation ( 3 ) with 5 and

$192a + 160b = 36$ ---( 5 )

$180a + 160b = 35$ -----( 6 )

Subtract ( 6 ) from ( 5 )

we get

$a = \frac{1}{ 12 }$

put $a = \frac{1}{12}$ in ( 3 )

we get ,

$b = 1/ 8$

Now $\frac{1}{ ( x + y ) }= 1/ 12 $

$\frac{1}{ ( x - y ) }= 1/ 8$

Therefore ,

$x + y = 12 $----( 7 )

$x - y = 8 $----- ( 8 )

add ( 7 ) and ( 8 )

$2x = 20$

$x = 10$

put x = 10 in ( 7 ) we get

$y = 2$

Speed of the boat in

still water =$ x $= $10$ kmph speed of the stream= $y $= $2$kmph

Comment: I appreciate your effort in typing you answer out, but I know that the difference between my answer and what you wrote (and what's given in the net) is that I've taken $ \frac{1}{x}=a $ and you (and they) have taken $ \frac{1}{x+y}=a $ .

My point is why isn't the answer turning out to be correct with my way

Comment: @PlopMon why do you need to follow that method when a easier one is available?Have you been strictly told by your instructor to follow that method?

Comment: @PlopMon you have substituted 1/x=m and 1/y=n which is absolutely not need and increase the time consumption to solve this problem.I have substituted 1/(x+y)to a and 1/(x-y)=b.Which is easier ,you tell me?

Comment: First of all I have not quoted this answer from any website,the variables might look same because I used to solve these kind of problems in grade 8 and the same variables were used by the books for proper understanding and readability.

Comment: I **get it** that that  two variables at a time to linear pair will make it much easier, but what's the harm in trying the other way around. After all it's Maths! if the solution is logical and ' _mistake-less_ ' then answer should be correct. 
My concern is regarding **why** the answer is not correct. And the tag and heading **clearly states** 'solution-VERIFICATION'

Comment: I have no issues with 'internet thingy' I'm just **generally** speaking that it was written/solved in the same manner. I said that because I had obviously searched for the solution to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73664/discussion-between-plopmon-and-calculus-programmer).

Comment: I hope I have explained you your mistake in the chat.